# best performance method to sum collection of collections

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a Collection named "cities"(class City) and each item in the collection has a member "streets" (class Street) and I want to iterate on all the cities and count the total number of streets in the collection.

what is the best way to do it using Streams while avoiding as many unnecessary operations (un\boxing, redundant calculations etc.)

Comment: It's a really simple stream operation, with no boxing at all. What have you tried, or are you just expecting us to write your code for you?

Comment: I am just not sure how to iterate on each of the sub-collections

Comment: Why do you assume streams = best performance?

Comment: Is iterating it like in the old good way is really better? Collectiosn shouldn't be huge, but few dozens (maybe hundreds) of items

Comment: Sequential streams usually won't get you better performance, but it can get you cleaner code, which is what you should usually aim for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int streetCount = cities
        .stream()
        .map(City::getStreets)
        .mapToInt(Collection::size)
        .sum();
```

Comment: Why count streets? Wouldn't it be faster to sum size of street collections?

Comment: @Andreas Beat me by a second :)